# configure, compile, and make memcached.a file instead of memcached executable

Tags: memcached, libmemcached

I am able to compile in Linux memcached into an executable. i am using 1.6.19 version source https://memcached.org/downloads/. there are two questions:

1. Can I build it for targets Windows, Mac, and Linux?
2. I want the memcached source file has to have a main function which compiles to an executable. Can I compile the memcached into a memcached.a file? I tried `make -i -B -d -o memcached.a` and it did not work.

I have seen the libmemcached.org tools for memcached server and was able to build them to .a files. What options do I have?

Comment: Not sure it will help you, but you can get a Windows native port here : https://github.com/jefyt/memcached-windows